# EOF within quoted string warning when merging csv files

Tags: r, csv, import, merge, read.csv

I have more than 70 CSV files and I am trying to merge them row-wise (they all have same columns). I tried to combine them using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(readr)
setwd("*\\data")
myfolder="test"
allfiles= list.files(path=myfolder, pattern="*.csv", full.names = T)
allfiles
combined_csv= ldply(allfiles, read.csv)
```

Once I run this code I get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

It looks like that I am losing some rows. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that same columns in different files are read as different types when some of them have some 'character' element and some are just numeric.  Here, is one method to read with all columns specified as "character" column, `rbind` the elements and then use `type.convert` to automatically convert the column classes based on the value it have

```
library(data.table)
out <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(path=myfolder, full.names = TRUE), 
       fread, colClasses = "character"))
out <- type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

myfolder="test" 

df <- list.files(path=myfolder, full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Comment: looks like this method is sensitive to the class of columns. I got this error message: 'Error: Can't combine `List Desig Agt 1 - CREA ID` <double> and `List Desig Agt 1 - CREA ID` <character>"'
It looks like the same column name has different class in two of excel sheets and that's why I got this error

Comment: I am not sure, but try this: `df <- list.files(path=myfolder, full.names = TRUE) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows `

Comment: Unfortunately gave the same error. when I expanded the error, it says: `Can't combine `List Desig Agt 1 - CREA ID` <double> and `List Desig Agt 1 - CREA ID` <character>.`

Comment: I wish I could share data here for more clarification but it's really hard as they are so many excel files

Comment: Try: `df <- list.files(path=myfolder, full.names = TRUE) %>% lapply(read_csv) %>%    bind_rows  %>% readr::type_convert()`